# SQL Server connect with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, dll

I have a php script that connects to SQL Server, locally it works fine because I was able to edit the php.ini to include the extension for php_mssql.dll. With the production server, it would be nice if I didn't have to restart the server, so is there a way to add the php_mssql.dll at the start of the script? If not, how can I check on the server (linux) to see if the php_mssql.dll file is available if I were to add it into the dynamic extensions section of the php.ini?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`dl()`](http://php.net/dl) function to load the plugin dynamically at runtime:

```
<?php

if (!extension_loaded('php_mssql')) {
   dl('php_mssql.dll');
}
```

Note that this has been disabled in PHP 5.3 when running in SAPI (in-webserver) mode.

Comment: I tried this and it's erroring when I get to my mssql_connect(). Is there a way to check to make sure the file that's needed is there for it to use? And if it isn't, how would I be able to get it?

Comment: `if (!dl('php_mssql.dll')) { die("Failed to load mssql extension."); }`

Comment: It's returning Failed to load mssql extension.

Comment: Then you'll have to figure out if that .dll is on the server. You're not going to have any luck with this unless it's there.

Answer (score 0):

To test if the mssql extension is loaded, use [`extension_loaded()`](http://php.net/manual/function.extension-loaded.php):

```
if (extension_loaded("php_mssql")) {}
```

Note that on Linux, it won't be a .dll, but rather a .so shared object library, and connections to MSSQL will probably require enabling the FreeTDS libraries on the Linux server.